# Use 27" Thunderbolt Display with iMac

Tags: imac, thunderbolt-display

I have an old MacBook Pro (2011) which I use with an [external 27" Thunderbolt Display](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Thunderbolt_Display). I'm now thinking about getting a new iMac. Is it possible to connect my Thunderbolt Display to the iMac as a secondary screen?

Answer (score 1):

Any Mac made in 2011 or newer has the Thunderbolt port needed to use this, so any new iMac would work fine.

Answer (score 0):

New iMac do have a thunderbolt port(not sure which model is the oldest that have one), it should have the thunderbolt port required for the display to work.